# Creating a set of players stored in SQL column

Tags: java, mysql

Is there a way to store a set of players in a column in a SQL database?

I have an events table and I want to store all players who have entered that event in the table under a column named `players`.

The entrants will all be from the `users` table.

I have found the set attribute but this looks like you need to specify specific values which the set can contain. I know these at the moment, but in the future, the `users` table is likely to change.

so I want to,

- add a column to the `events` table called `players` that contains a set of `users`
- this should be empty initially but then as players are entered into that event, they are added to the set.
- from the java side of things, when I read the data from the database, it will take the event and display the name and then show all the users who are in the `players` set.

Is this the way I should be doing it? or is there a better way? i.e storing the users in an event in a set, storing this in some way in the database, and then reading this data back into the set in java before displaying it?

I am thinking I can store the `id` from the `users` table as a foreign key so in the set it will for example have users 1,3,4,7 in the set of players. Then when I get that data back I can display the users name in the web app.

Thanks

Comment: The `have users 1,3,4,7` is the worst possible solution. You need to create a `link` table that links a User to an Event. A simple table that contains `user_id, event_id`

Answer (score 1):

You have a multi-valued attribute. That is, a team has players, but there are multiple players in a given team.

But SQL naturally wants each column to store *one* value in a given row. This makes it easier to add a member with INSERT by creating a new row, or removing a member with DELETE of one row.

Because of the assumption that a column stores one value, the FOREIGN KEY constraint does not support comma-separated lists. Neither do simple expressions using `=` to compare a column to another value for searching or joining.

You should read my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574) for more examples.

Instead, a multi-valued attribute needs to be stored on multiple rows of a second table.

```
CREATE TABLE players (
  event_id INT NOT NULL,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_id, user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Now you can add many users for a given event. A given user may attend many events. It's easy to insert a player, or remove a player. It's easy to count how many players for a given event, or how many events a given user has played at. And lots of other operations.

This is way better than using comma-separated lists.

This is the table design you arrive at if you follow [rules of relational database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).